# Scrapy callback request not working

Tags: python, scrapy, screen-scraping

I'm trying to scrape [this site](https://www.coldwellbankerhomes.com/fl/miami-dade-county/kvc-17_1,17_3,17_2,17_8/incl-22/). I'm using Scrapy's `Request` but it is not working and the code is showing unusual behavior. Below is my code:

```
        # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

        from scrapy.spiders import BaseSpider
        from scrapy.selector import Selector
        from scrapy.http import Request,Response
        import re
        import csv
        import time

        from selenium import webdriver



        class ColdWellSpider(BaseSpider):
            name = "cwspider"
            allowed_domains = ["coldwellbankerhomes.com"]
            #start_urls = [''.join(row).strip() for row in csv.reader(open("remaining_links.csv"))]
            #start_urls = ['https://www.coldwellbankerhomes.com/fl/boynton-beach/5451-verona-drive-unit-d/pid_9266204/']
            start_urls = ['https://www.coldwellbankerhomes.com/fl/miami-dade-county/kvc-17_1,17_3,17_2,17_8/incl-22/']

            def parse(self,response):

                    #browser = webdriver.PhantomJS(service_args=['--ignore-ssl-errors=true', '--load-images=false'])
                    browser = webdriver.Firefox()
                    browser.maximize_window()
                    browser.get(response.url)
                    time.sleep(5)

                    #to extract all the links from a page and send request to those links
                    self.getlink(response)

                    #for clicking the load more button in the page 
                    while True:
                        try:
                            browser.find_element_by_class_name('search-results-load-more').find_element_by_tag_name('a').click()
                            time.sleep(3)
                            self.getlink(browser)

                        except:
                            break

            def getlink(self,response):
                print 'hhelo'

                c = open('data_getlink.csv', 'a')
                d = csv.writer(c, lineterminator='\n')
                print 'hello2'
                listclass = response.xpath('//div[@class="list-items"]/div[contains(@id,"snapshot")]')

                for l in listclass:
                       link = 'http://www.coldwellbankerhomes.com/'+''.join(l.xpath('./h2/a/@href').extract())

                       d.writerow([link])
                       yield Request(url = str(link),callback=self.parse_link)


           #callback function of Request
           def parse_link(self,response):
                    b = open('data_parselink.csv', 'a')
                    a = csv.writer(b, lineterminator='\n')
                    a.writerow([response.url])
```

Th problem is with `yield Request(url = str(link),callback=self.parse_link)`. As i remove this line of code , the `getlink` function is perfectly called and the links are written to the `data_getlink.csv` file. But if the above line is present in the code the whole getlink function is not called and hence the callback function as well. Any help would be really useful

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with `yield` statement.

When `yield` statement is present, `getlink` function becomes an iterator function, so its body is not executed until first iterated item is requested.

To fix that, call `getlink` function this way:

```
for i in self.getlink(browser): # actually, browser or response here?
    yield i
```

or in python3:

```
yield from self.getlink(browser)
```